# Wrap java assert with Groovy assert, using AST transformation

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to do this, I call the method (from my framework),

```
assertFromLib("TestCaseName",Foo.bar == 'something') //java code
```

with test case name as `TestCaseName` and the assert condition as `Foo.bar == 'something'`.

Under the hood, Junit assert is used to assert the test case. But if it fails, we are not getting any messages like groovy assertions.

What I'm looking for here is when this method is called anywhere in my codebase,  I need to get the paramater `Foo.bar == 'something'` (without executing i.e resulting to boolean) and wrap with

```
assert Foo.bar == 'something'
```

Here the assert is the assert from Groovy, so that if the case fails, I can get nice messages of why it got failed!

Basically I need wrap the java assert with groovy assert to get nice error messages.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's unclear. Can You clarify? Or provide a working example?

Comment: I have made changes to the question.

Comment: And that assertFromLib("TestCaseName",Foo.bar == 'something') is supposed to be in Java code?

Comment: Ya the code `assertFromLib("TestCaseName",Foo.bar == 'something')` will be in Java.